# php parser, что моло пойти не так?

Tags: php, парсер

Попросили спарсить цены на 1 продукт в разных магазинах.

Всего 5 магазинов.

4 получилось без проблем.

А вот с 5 никак.  То есть совсем.

Пробовал simple html dom, DiDom. Не получается.

Так как я в парсиге не являюсь спецом. То даже не представляю что не так, и в какую сторону копать.

Может подскажите в чём может быть дело. Ну а если рабочий пример, было бы вообще чудесно.
goldapple.ru/10004-15250700094-clinique-id-bb-gel

```
require_once('simplehtmldom_1_9_1/simple_html_dom.php'); 
$html = new simple_html_dom(); 
$html->load_file('goldapple.ru/10004-15250700094-clinique-id-bb-gel'); 
echo $html;
```

Comment: показывайте код вашего парсера, какие ошибки возникли в процессе его работы

Answer (score -1):

1. Находишь любой элемент `[id^="product-price-"]`
2. Достаёшь у него значение из атрибута `data-price-amount`

PS: Я б вообще регуляркой достал.

Comment: Да дело в том, что я могу в результате ничего выбрать. Скрипт повисает или циклится.

@And Спасибо за правку оформления.

Comment: @user2196016, на странице данные есть. Если у тебя что-то циклится, то ты где-то накосячил.

Comment: Тот же код на 4 других сайтах работает адекватно. А на этом... может защита от парсинга... Я поэтому и спрашивать стал. Думал кто нить с опытом проверит и выскажеться